# Store input in a 2-dimensional list - Python 3x - BMI program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python just FYI.  I am taking input as patients name, patient ID number, height, and weight which I have functional code for calculating their Body Mass Index.  The user can continue storing input until they "quit" or enter a negative value for patientID.

**Problem**: I also need to store these inputs in a 2-dimensional list (list of lists) then be able to out put a report of all patients names followed by their BMI number, plus state the category (obese, underweight etc) that I already calculated.  Below is all my code that works so far (although not pretty):

```
# Give the user input options.
print("\nWelcome to patient entry. What would you like to do?")

# Set an initial value for choice other than the value for 'quit'.
choice = ''

# Start a loop that runs until the user enters the value for 'quit'.
while choice != 'q':
    # Give all the choices in a series of print statements.
    print("\n[1] Enter Patient Info.")
    print("[q] Enter q to quit.")

# Ask for the user's choice.
    choice = input("\nWhat would you like to do? ")

# Respond to the user's choice.
    if choice == '1':
        patient_name = (input("Enter patient name: "))
        patient_id = int(input("Enter patient ID number: "))

        while True:
            height = int(input("Enter your height in inches: "))
            try:
                val = int(height)
                if val < 0:  # if not a positive, ask for input again
                    print("Sorry, input has to be a positive number, try again")

                break
            except ValueError:
                print("That's not an number!")

        while True:
            weight = int(input("Enter your weight in pounds: "))

            try:
                val = int(weight)
                if val < 0:  # if not a positive int, ask for input again
                    print("Sorry, input has to be a positive number, try again")
                    continue
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("That's not an number!")

        # CDC formulat--https://www.cdc.gov/nccdphp/dnpao/growthcharts/training/bmiage/page5_2.html
        BMI = ((float(weight) / float(height) ** 2) * 703)

        # print(f"Your BMI is {BMI}")

        print("Your BMI is: {0} and you are: ".format(round(BMI, 2)), end='')

        # conditions
        if (BMI < 16):
            print("severely underweight")

        elif (BMI >= 16 and BMI < 18.5):
            print("underweight")

        elif (BMI >= 18.5 and BMI < 25):
            print("Healthy")

        elif (BMI >= 25 and BMI < 30):
            print("overweight")

        elif (BMI >= 30):
            print("severely overweight")

    elif choice == 'q':
        print("\nThanks for playing. See you later.\n")
        exit()
    else:
        print("\nI don't understand that choice, please try again.\n")

patient_name = (input("Enter patient name: "))
patient_id = int(input("Enter patient ID number: "))

while True:
  height = int(input("Enter your height in inches: "))
  try:
        val = int(height)
        if val < 0:  # if not a positive, ask for input again
            print("Sorry, input has to be a positive number, try again")
            continue
        break
  except ValueError:
    print("That's not an number!")

while True:
  weight = int(input("Enter your weight in pounds: "))

  try:
        val = int(weight)
        if val < 0:  # if not a positive int, ask for input again
            print("Sorry, input has to be a positive number, try again")
            continue
        break
  except ValueError:
        print("That's not an number!")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a list in which you can add other lists containing patient data.

```
myList = []
```

Now, once you have taken all the required inputs for a single patient in 1 iteration of a loop, its time to create a new list (sub-array). I also noticed that you need category as well but after your calculation, you are only printing it. So, create a variable and store it as well.

```
subList = [patient_name, patient_id, height, weight] #add remaining values as well
```

Finally, add the `subList` to the `myList` to create a 2 dimensional list like this:

```
myList.append(subList)
```

To iterate over this 2-d list, you can do something list this:

```
for patientData in myList:
    print(patientData)
```